# An "powered vector space"?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

In a conversation with a friend some non-rigorous dumb ideas emerged. So I have a naive question and could be a non-sense as well.

So consider basic linear algebra; a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^{*}$. **Do exist some algebraic structure like the following?**

> $$ V^{V} $$
>
> $$ V^{V^{*}} $$
> *Some sort of "powered vector spaces"*

Comment: A symbol is not an algebraic structure. You need to say more about what you are expecting to find.

Comment: @ZhenLin I agree with you, but I don't know more than just "a powered vector space" imprecise and rough idea. Maybe we can close this question because I think that I won't develop it further.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ means the set of all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, so what you have may be understood as sth of this sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given sets $A$ and $B$, one denotes by $A^B$ the set of all functions $B\to A$. The cardinality of $|A^B|$ equals $|A|^{|B|}$. A particular instance is the cartesian power $A^n$, since every $n$-uple $a = (a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is just a way to denote a map $a:\{1,\ldots n\}\to A$, with $a(i)=a_i$.

If $V$ is a vector space and $B$ is any set, then $V^B$ is a vector space with operations inherited from $V$. Namely, if $f,g\in V^B$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb K$, one defines $(f+\lambda g)(b) = f(b) + \lambda g(b)$, where the operations at the right happen in $V$. The zero element of $V^B$ is the constant function equal to the zero of $V$.

If $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $V$ and $X\subseteq V^B$ is the subspace of functions with finite support, then one constructs a basis for $X$ by $(f_{b,i})_{(b,i)\in B\times I}$ via $$f_{b,i}(b') =\begin{cases} v_i \mbox{ if }b'=b \\ 0\mbox{ else } \end{cases}$$

Proof: let $f\in X$ be supported at $\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$. For each $j \in \{1,\ldots, m\}$, write $f(b_j) = \sum_{i \in I_{j}} a_{ij}v_i$, where $I_j\subseteq I$ is finite and $a_{ij}\in \Bbb K$. Then $$f = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i\in I_j} a_{ij} f_{b_j,i}.$$This shows that $(f_{b,i})_{(b,i)\in B\times I}$ spans $X$.

For linear independence, assume that given any finite subset $\{b_1,\ldots, b_m\}\times I_0\subseteq B\times I_0$ we have that $$\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i \in I_0} a_{ij}f_{b_j,i}=0$$for some $a_{ij}\in \Bbb K$. The goal is to show that all of those coefficients are zero. Evaluate at $b_k$ to get $$0=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i\in I_0} a_{ij}f_{b_j,i}(b_k)=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i\in I_0} a_{ij}\delta_{jk}v_i = \sum_{i\in I_0} a_{ik}v_i.$$By linear independence of the basis chosen for $V$ we get $a_{ik}=0$ for all $k \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $i \in I_0$. We are done. So $\dim X = |B|\dim V$.