# Dimension of $V^X$ where $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and X is any nonempty set.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $X$ be any nonempty set, V be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

$\ V^X:=\{f:X \rightarrow V\}$. This is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Now I want to find the dimension of $V^X$ in terms of the cardinality of $X$ and the dimension of $V$.

If $X$ is finite and $V$ is finite-dimensional then $dim(V^X)=|X|\times dim(V)$.

Let $B:=\{b_1,b_2,...b_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ and $X:=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$.

Let $B^X:=\{f_{x_i}^{b^j}: 1\leq i\leq k \ \  \text{and} \ \ 1\leq j \leq n\ \  \text{where} f_{x_i}^{b^j}(x_l)=\delta_{il}b_j\} \subset V^X$.
$B^X$ is a basis of $V^X$ and $|B^X|=|X|\times dim(V)$.

If $X$ is infinite and $V$ has infinite-dimension then what can be said about $dim(V^X)$?

Comment: $\dim V^X \geq |X|\dim V$ in all possible situations. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3874469/118056).

Comment: With equality holds iff $X$ and $dim(V)$ are finite. Can I say this?